# Covariant return types and static classes

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Please have a look at the function below:

```
Public Function Test(ByVal i As Integer) As Animal
        If i = 1 Then
            Return New Dog
        Else
            Return New Cat
        End If

    End Function
```

A dog or a cat is returned by the function depending on whether the value of the integer is 1 or not.  How is this approached if Dog and Cat are Static classes? i.e. you cannot create an instance of a static class.  I have read a few webpages on the MSDN website this afternoon talking about static classes, but I have not found an answer to my specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term "static class" is a C# concept, it doesn't exist in VB.NET.  So, no, this isn't possible.

It isn't possible in C# either, a static class can only derive from Object.  The closest VB.NET equivalent of a static class is Module.  Quite unsuitable.

You can certainly return a static *instance* of a class.  Declare the variable in a Module or use the Shared keyword if you want to declare it inside a class.

```
Class Example 
    Private Shared theDog As Dog
    Private Shared theCat As Cat

    Public Shared Function Test(ByVal i As Integer) As Animal
        If i = 1 Then Return theDog Else Return theCat
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  In my case the function cannot be static because I have to access and populate an instance variable that is not static (I realise that I did not mention this in the question).  Sorry.

Comment: Well, of course I picked Shared because the function isn't using any instance members of the class.  Feel free to remove it.  Strange comment btw, are you sure you know what you are asking for?

Answer (score 0):

> How is this approached if Dog and Cat are Static classes?

This isn't.  You can't "return a static class" - you need to always return an object.  You could *use* a static/shared method on a class to generate or operate on the object.  For example, if you had a factory creation method on the types, you could do something like:

```
Public Function Test(ByVal i As Integer) As Animal
    If i = 1 Then
        Return Dog.Create(i)
    Else
        Return Cat.Create(i)
    End If

End Function
```